# Why does sorting this list work outside but not inside function?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have the following function

```
def resample(series, maxerror):

  output = []
  process(series, maxerror, output)

  return output
```

I am calling it from another file like this and then sorting it

```
fdata = compression.resample(cdata[xn:end], 0.08)
fdata.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

This works. However, when I try to put the sorting line in the function itself before it returns output, it doesn't work....why not?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Note:  `key=lambda x: x[0]` seems unnecessary as the default compare will compare on `x[0]` first (then `x[1]`, `x[2]`, etc.).  The only reason to use the `lambda` is to stop subordering.

Comment: Depending on what `process` is, it might be a threading issue where sorting inside the function happens before output has actually received the data. You could try that by adding a `time.sleep` call between process and sorting (still using Adam's comments.

Comment: @deinonychusaur just tried that still not working ... very strange

Answer (score 1):

My strong guess is that you're doing `return output.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]`. `list.sort` ALWAYS returns `None`, as it works in-place.

Instead do

```
return sorted(output, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Alternatively:

```
output.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
return output
```

Comment: Why not sort the list in place and then return?

Comment: Or alternatively, if in-place is desirable, call `.sort` on a separate line from `return`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham:  I agree.  You have a list you're about to throw away.  Sort then return seems better than making a sorted copy.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No reason. I personally prefer to create a new sorted object, which leaves any logging I do to give the actual input. I've included both methods, now.

Comment: If OP owns `process` as well, he might be able to do the sorting at insert time also (when initially constructing the list, maybe controlled with an optional `sorted` boolean argument), for an additional performance gain.

Comment: I've tried both of these and it isn't working...no error or anything. When applied outside of the function it works.